# Find all possible sums from two number sequences of length n and insert them into a hash table in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, time-complexity, pseudocode

So the question I'm trying to solve is as follows:

> The input is a sequence of n numbers {x1, x2, . . . , xn}, another
>   sequence of n numbers {y1, y2, . . . , yn}, and a number z. Your
>   algorithm should determine whether or not z ∈ {xi + yj | 1 ≤ i, j ≤
>   n}. You should use universal hashing families, and your algorithm
>   should run in expected time O(n).
>
> Provide justification that your algorithm is correct and runs in the
>   required time. Be very clear about which theorems from class and/or
>   the text you are using, and how.

So far, I've come up with this algorithm for finding all possible sums, inserting them into the hash table and then searching for `z`:

```
for (i in x; i++) {
    for (j in y; j++) {
        sum = xi + yj;
        insert_into_hash_table(T, sum);
    }
}

search_hash_table(T, z);
```

The only problem is that the worst-case time here is `O(n^2)`.

How do I do this in `O(n)`?? =S

Comment: This looks like homework, so just a hint.  Perhaps you might think in terms of xi and (z - xi).

Comment: Title is misleading, in that the problem does not require forming all sums between the x_i and y_i and hashing.  It just appears that way from the problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put all `Yi`  to a `map`.

Now once you have `Z`:

```
 for all values from Xi
     find if Z - Xi os present in map
```

Comment: But doesn't this still take O(n^2) time? Since worst case, we have to go through all numbers in x AND y?

Comment: @aditi Nope it takes O(N). Creating a map is O(N) and traversing the Xi is also O(N). O(N) + O(N) ~ O(N). Hope you understand.

Comment: @aditi No.  Think about it.  If that doesn't help, then run through a simple example by hand.  x = {5, 10, 15} y = {2, 4, 6} z = 8, z = 12

Comment: Oh crap yes! I was thinking about it o(n) * o(n) for some reason. This makes sense with addition - the highest degree is still o(n). Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all numbers of x into a hash table T, and determine if (Z-y) is in T.
This needs on scan of X, and one scan of Y.

```
T = set()
for x in X:
    T.add(x)
for y in Y:
    if (Z-y) in T:
        return TRUE
```